# Chrome Extension + Firebase - Calling firebase.database() in background, content and popup scripts equal new connection for each?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-chrome-extension

In Chrome Extensions we have around 3 different scripts that may run at once, a persistent background page running on a browser window, a content script for a single website and finally the popup script when a user presses the extension button.

I need to connect to my `firebase.database()` instance in all of these. They all use the same firebase app and database. Does firebase know somehow from all these different scripts to open one connection or are they all creating new ones? This is concerning the simultaneous connection limit.

Comment: These are 3 different pages each with its own URL so there'll be 3 connections.

Comment: Sounds like an answer @wOxxOm. :-)

Comment: Ah the legendary Frank from Firebase! @wOxxOm if you write out the an answer I'll be happy to accept it. Just to expand, there's no way for firebase to use an existing socket connection in the same browser instance right? Do you guys think I should confine the instance to the background page and use chrome.messages to relay data or open one and quickly close it with db.goOffline() ?

Comment: Actually I'll just use the local storage and retrieve the data from there!

Answer (score 0):

When you call the firebase.database() method, Firebase uses the authentication token to open a database connection. This connection is shared by all scripts that use the same authentication token.

So in your case, all three instances of firebase.database() that you use will create a single database connection. This means you will only have to worry about the simultaneous connection limit once.